Error when using Chilkat.dll on My Watch data USB Key
Receiving the attached error when using Chilkat.dll on My Watch data USB Key. Does anybody know a solution?
The application was running fine with Epass-2003 USB Key. We received a new USB Key "Watch Data Ukey", I changed the token ID and Password as per the new key, and I am getting the error below.
Updated Chilkat.dll version to the latest one. And tried restarting smartcard in services. MSc. tried system re boot. Some Ai Bots are suggesting it as CCID IS ENGAGED is causing the issue, tried to lock out the other apps using this ccid.
Error ScreenShot:

Error Log:
ChilkatLog:
  AcquireContext:
    DllDate: Mar 29 2024
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.98
    UnlockStatus: 1
    Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit
    Language: .NET 4.5 / x64 / VS2013
    VerboseLogging: 0
    acquireContext(31ms):
      readerName: Watchdata WDIND USB CCID Key 0
      connectToCardInReader:
        reader: Watchdata WDIND USB CCID Key 0
        shareMode: shared
        preferredProtocol: no_preference
      --connectToCardInReader
      ATR: 3B6D00005744364101869311117A0F6678
      checkKnownAtrs:
        ATR: 3B6D00005744364101869311117A0F6678
      --checkKnownAtrs
      lookupCardInfoByAtr:
        calaisRegLookup:
          atrToFind: 3b6d00005744364101869311117a0f6678
          openedKey: SOFTWARE
          openedKey: Microsoft
          openedKey: Cryptography
          openedKey: Calais
          openedKey: SmartCards
          Opened SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Cryptography/Calais/SmartCards
          RegistryQueryError: The system cannot find the file specified.
          ValueName: 80000001
          RegistryQueryError: The system cannot find the file specified.
          ValueName: Smart Card Key Storage Provider
          dllFilename: 
          The missing 80000001 entry indicates this card may not have a Minidriver interface...
          cryptoProvider: PROXKey CSP India V3.0
          smartCardKeyStorageProvider: 
          Found ATR in SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Cryptography/Calais/SmartCards!
        --calaisRegLookup
      --lookupCardInfoByAtr
      cardName: WD_Ultimate Key Minidriver
      dllFilename: 
      cryptoProv: PROXKey CSP India V3.0
      keyStorageProv: 
      This card may not not support the ScMinidriver API.
      It may support CNG and/or PKCS11..
      Using the default Windows minidriver msclmd.dll
      Loaded minidriver DLL.
      cardData_atr: 3B6D00005744364101869311117A0F6678
      cardData_cardName: WD_Ultimate Key Minidriver
      Calling CardAcquireContext with CARD_DATA version=7
      WindowsError: An unexpected card error has occurred.
      scardError: 0x8010001f
      Retry CardAcquireContext with CARD_DATA version=6
      WindowsError: An unexpected card error has occurred.
      scardError: 0x8010001f
      Retry CardAcquireContext with CARD_DATA version=5
      WindowsError: Indicates two revision levels are incompatible.
      scardError: 0x51a
      Failed.
    --acquireContext
    Failed.
  --AcquireContext
--ChilkatLog


Don't use ScMinidriver with the WatchData token.  Instead, use PKCS11.  With Chilkat v9.5.0.98 and later, you can call Chilkat.Cert.LoadFromSmartcard(""), and Chilkat will automatically recognize the WatchData token because of the ATR, and Chilkat will automatically choose to use PKCS11 w/ the driver being %WINDIR/System32/SignatureP11.dll
You can alternatively use the Chilkat.Pkcs11 class if you wish for a lower-level API with greater control.

PS> A note to smart  card vendors: Please fully document the ATR's for any given smart card, including the composition/structure of the ATR's and which parts are variable and which parts are not.  Also, please fully document the PKCS11 (and ScMinidriver) DLL filenames (and .so/.dylib filenames for non-Windows systems).  Also  please fully document the CSP names for CNG/CAPI access, if supported.  Software vendors such as Chilkat would greatly appreciate better documentation.
